# I have to show that the double serie diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to show that the double serie $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ((\frac{1}{k+1} \cdot (\frac{k}{k+1})^{i}) - (\frac{1}{k+2} \cdot (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^{i}))$$ convergence to $-\frac{1}{2}$.
Wolfram Alpha also says this series convergence to $-\frac{1}{2}$. Unfortunately, I don't know the calculation route.

Comment: It would be good to check [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: The inner sum telescopes

Comment: The inner sum is a geometric series...

Answer (score 0):

i think i am at the end.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ((\frac{1}{k+1} \cdot (\frac{k}{k+1})^{i}) - (\frac{1}{k+2} \cdot (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^{i}))$$

=

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \cdot (\frac{k}{k+1})^{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+2} \cdot (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^{i}$$

=

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\frac{k}{k+1})^{i} - \frac{1}{k+2} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\frac{k+1}{k+2})^{i}$$

=(geometric series)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \cdot (k) - \frac{1}{k+2} \cdot  (k+1)$$

=

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{k^{2} + 3k + 2}$$
Now a little hint is still missing to finish.

Comment: Hint: Use partial fraction to turn the fraction into sum/difference of two fractions.